# ios - core data not fetching when running on device

Tags: ios, core-data, device

My app is running ok in the simulator, but when I run it on device, it does not show the fetched results!

Code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Jobs" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? Is this data you enter in the app, or is it from a built-in pre-populated data store?